# How to get value from JSON - Python

Tags: python, json, list, rest, xpath

If anyone can help me to get a value from a json response. I intend to get only the first incidence of id where the type is CLIENTREF.
I am reading a list to get some values to do a GET and check if the response is other than null "".

This is the JSON structure:

This is my code so far

```
def checkParent(list):
    for item in list:
        cdwParenturl = f"http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties/{item}/?yyyy-mm-dd={dateinplay}"

        r = requests.get(cdwParenturl).json()
        jsonpath_expression = parse("$..identifier[*]")
        # $..identifier[?(@.type == 'CLIENTREF')].id
        parentId = []

        for match in jsonpath_expression.find(r):
            # print(f"match id: {match.value}")
            thisdict = match.value
        if thisdict["type"] == "CLIENTREF":
            #   print(thisdict["id"])
            parentId.append(thisdict["id"])
        elif thisdict["id"] == "":
            print(colored(f"The parent {item} does not have ultimateParent", "red"))
        print(colored(f"All counterparties have parent", "green"))

checkParent(r_mheu_trade)
```

print(f "match id: {match.value}") I get this, What I need is the first id related to the type: CLIENTREF

The error that appears on my console is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\DESKTOP\test_check\checkCounterpartie.py", line 114, in <module>
    checkParent(r_mheu_trade)
  File "h:\DESKTOP\test_check\checkCounterpartie.py", line 106, in checkParent
    if thisdict["type"] == "CLIENTREF":
KeyError: 'type'
```

Comment: Please avoid using keywords as variable names like  ```list```  in your case.Assuming your json file is assigned to avariable called ```json1``` you'd reach ```CLIENTREF``` this way ```json1[0]['riskUltimateParent']['identifier'][1]```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply pyzer, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of pyzer I found a solution to my problem. This is how the code looks like:

```
# Request to get all UltimateParent
def checkParent(murex):
    for item in murex:
        cdwParenturl = f"http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties/{item}/?yyyy-mm-dd={dateinplay}"

        r = requests.get(cdwParenturl).json()
        clientref = r[0]["riskUltimateParent"]["identifier"][1]
        
        if clientref == "":
           print(colored(f"The parent {item} does not have ultimateParent", "red"))
        else:
            print(colored(f"All counterparties have parent", "green")) 

checkParent(r_mheu_trade)
```